# Ajax 500 Internal Server but gets deleted after refresh and in Django models

Tags: ajax, django, datatables

I am using Django and Datatables and I'm doing something like a batch deleting functionality for the ListView.

When I click the Delete button, it displays a `POST 500 (Internal Server Error)`. But when I refresh the page it gets deleted successfully.

```
'action': function() {
    // count check used for checking selected items.
    var count = table.rows({
        selected: true
    }).count();

    if (count > 0) {
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure you want to delete these items?",
            text: "There is NO undo!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            // confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes",
            cancelButtonText: "No",
            closeOnConfirm: true,
        }, function(isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                var data = table.rows({
                    selected: true
                }).data();

                var list = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    // alert(data[i][2]);
                    list.push(data[i][2]);
                }

                var sData = list.join();

                // alert(sData)
                document.getElementById('delete_items_list').value = sData;

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                        }
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: window.location.href,
                    data: {
                        'ids': sData
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        // Update page
                        window.location.reload();
                        swal("Deleted!", "The selected item/s were successfully deleted.", "success");
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        // Display message or something else
                        // swal("Error deleting!", "Please try again.", "error");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        swal("Error!", "You didn't select any items.", "error");
        return false;
    }
},
```

This is my views.py in the Part (Class-Based Generic ListView):

```
class PartListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    model = Part

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ids = self.request.POST.get('ids')
        ids = ids.split(",")
        # try:
            # Check ids are valid numbers
            # ids = map(int, ids)
        # except ValueError as e:
        #     return JsonResponse(status=400)
        # delete items
        self.model.objects.filter(id__in=ids).delete()
        return reverse('part')
        # return JsonResponse({"status": "ok"}, status=204)



    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PartListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        context['activate'] = 'part'
        return context
```

I also want to display a `swal("Deleted!", "The selected item/s were successfully deleted.", "success");` sweetalert **after** the page reloads, but it doesn't work. This is probably the reason why it doesn't show up or something.. because of the 500 Internal Server Error.

How do I fix this? Thank you in advance!

This is what the UI looks like..
[image]

Traceback:

```
AttributeError at /part/
'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/part/
Django Version: 2.0.2
Python Executable: C:\Ken\deltainventory\myvenv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path: ['C:\\Ken\\deltainventory', 'C:\\Ken\\deltainventory\\myvenv\\Scripts\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Python36', 'C:\\Ken\\deltainventory\\myvenv', 'C:\\Ken\\deltainventory\\myvenv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time: Thu, 22 Feb 2018 11:56:09 +0800
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'inventory',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'sweetify']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "C:\Ken\deltainventory\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Ken\deltainventory\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__
  97.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "C:\Ken\deltainventory\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
  26.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /part/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Request information:
USER: admin

GET: No GET data

POST:
ids = '71'

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES:
sessionid = 'i9h2ts33s15n5ufcvuzanut5a01f54z7'
_ga = 'GA1.1.1743870208.1519265216'
_gid = 'GA1.1.1997363703.1519265216'
_gat = '1'

META:
ALLUSERSPROFILE = 'C:\\ProgramData'
ANSICON = '73x32766 (73x21)'
ANSICON_DEF = '7'
APPDATA = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES = 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86) = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMW6432 = 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
COMPUTERNAME = 'IT06062016-PC'
COMSPEC = 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe'
CONEMUANSI = 'ON'
CONEMUANSILOG = ''
CONEMUARGS = ''
CONEMUARGS2 = ''
CONEMUBACKHWND = '0x000202B8'
CONEMUBASEDIR = 'E:\\kendjango jan 29\\ConEmu Portable 171226\\ConEmu'
CONEMUBASEDIRSHORT = 'E:\\kendjango jan 29\\ConEmu Portable 171226\\ConEmu'
CONEMUBUILD = '171226'
CONEMUCFGDIR = 'E:\\kendjango jan 29\\ConEmu Portable 171226'
CONEMUCONFIG = ''
CONEMUDIR = 'E:\\kendjango jan 29\\ConEmu Portable 171226'
CONEMUDRAWHWND = '0x000202B6'
CONEMUDRIVE = 'E:'
CONEMUHOOKS = 'Enabled'
CONEMUHWND = '0x000202A0'
CONEMUISADMIN = 'ADMIN'
CONEMUPALETTE = '<Current color scheme>'
CONEMUPID = '4412'
CONEMUPROMPT0 = '$E[m$E[32m$E]9;8;"USERNAME"$E\\@$E]9;8;"COMPUTERNAME"$E\\$S'
CONEMUPROMPT1 = '$E[m$E[32m$E]9;8;"USERNAME"$E\\@$E]9;8;"COMPUTERNAME"$E\\$S$E[92m$P$E[90m'
CONEMUPROMPT2 = '$_$E[90m$$'
CONEMUPROMPT3 = '$E[m$S$E]9;12$E\\'
CONEMUSERVERPID = '2452'
CONEMUTASK = '{Shells::cmd}'
CONEMUWORKDIR = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator'
CONEMUWORKDRIVE = 'C:'
CONTENT_LENGTH = '6'
CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
CSRF_COOKIE = '5iKoTML7QZIkPSxkhBURue1sujhVwOvc0mvC4dngtR712KJ1HTokzSzDhG7z5zVG'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'deltainventory.settings'
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK = 'NO'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = 'CGI/1.1'
HOMEDRIVE = 'C:'
HOMEPATH = '\\Users\\Administrator'
HTTP_ACCEPT = '*/*'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = 'gzip, deflate, br'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
HTTP_CONNECTION = 'keep-alive'
HTTP_COOKIE = 'sessionid=i9h2ts33s15n5ufcvuzanut5a01f54z7; _ga=GA1.1.1743870208.1519265216; _gid=GA1.1.1997363703.1519265216; _gat=1'
HTTP_HOST = '127.0.0.1:8000'
HTTP_ORIGIN = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
HTTP_REFERER = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/part/'
HTTP_USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36'
HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN = 'IsFQFHqDnOMyFtsEaNxHIlGOLmy5uHRgDwq4Q82M0GbfSlElA51aNZeZyJoJ3shK'
HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH = 'XMLHttpRequest'
LOCALAPPDATA = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local'
LOGONSERVER = '\\\\IT06062016-PC'
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = '4'
OS = 'Windows_NT'
PATH = 'C:\\Ken\\deltainventory\\myvenv\\Scripts;E:\\kendjango jan 29\\ConEmu Portable 171226\\ConEmu\\Scripts;E:\\kendjango jan 29\\ConEmu Portable 171226;E:\\kendjango jan 29\\ConEmu Portable 171226\\ConEmu;C:\\Python36\\Scripts\\;C:\\Python36\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program Files\\Broadcom\\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\\Driver;;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\OpenCL SDK\\2.0\\bin\\x86;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\OpenCL SDK\\2.0\\bin\\x64;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files\\WIDCOMM\\Bluetooth Software\\;C:\\Program Files\\WIDCOMM\\Bluetooth Software\\syswow64'
PATHEXT = '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW'
PATH_INFO = '/part/'
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = 'AMD64'
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel'
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = '6'
PROCESSOR_REVISION = '3a09'
PROGRAMDATA = 'C:\\ProgramData'
PROGRAMFILES = 'C:\\Program Files'
PROGRAMFILES(X86) = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
PROGRAMW6432 = 'C:\\Program Files'
PROMPT = '(myvenv) $E[m$E[32m$E]9;8;"USERNAME"$E\\@$E]9;8;"COMPUTERNAME"$E\\$S$E[92m$P$E[90m$_$E[90m$$$E[m$S$E]9;12$E\\'
PSMODULEPATH = 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\'
PUBLIC = 'C:\\Users\\Public'
QUERY_STRING = ''
REMOTE_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_HOST = ''
REQUEST_METHOD = 'POST'
RUN_MAIN = 'true'
SCRIPT_NAME = ''
SERVER_NAME = 'IT06062016-PC'
SERVER_PORT = '8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE = 'WSGIServer/0.2'
SESSIONNAME = 'Console'
SYSTEMDRIVE = 'C:'
SYSTEMROOT = 'C:\\Windows'
TEMP = 'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
TMP = 'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
USERDOMAIN = 'IT06062016-PC'
USERNAME = 'Administrator'
USERPROFILE = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator'
VIRTUAL_ENV = 'C:\\Ken\\deltainventory\\myvenv'
WINDIR = 'C:\\Windows'
WINDOWS_TRACING_FLAGS = '3'
WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE = 'C:\\BVTBin\\Tests\\installpackage\\csilogfile.log'
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH = 'E:\\kendjango jan 29\\ConEmu Portable 171226\\ConEmu\\Scripts;E:\\kendjango jan 29\\ConEmu Portable 171226;E:\\kendjango jan 29\\ConEmu Portable 171226\\ConEmu;C:\\Python36\\Scripts\\;C:\\Python36\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program Files\\Broadcom\\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\\Driver;;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\OpenCL SDK\\2.0\\bin\\x86;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\OpenCL SDK\\2.0\\bin\\x64;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files\\WIDCOMM\\Bluetooth Software\\;C:\\Program Files\\WIDCOMM\\Bluetooth Software\\syswow64'
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT = '$E[m$E[32m$E]9;8;"USERNAME"$E\\@$E]9;8;"COMPUTERNAME"$E\\$S$E[92m$P$E[90m$_$E[90m$$$E[m$S$E]9;12$E\\'
wsgi.errors = <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper = ''
wsgi.input = <_io.BufferedReader name=948>
wsgi.multiprocess = False
wsgi.multithread = True
wsgi.run_once = False
wsgi.url_scheme = 'http'
wsgi.version = '(1, 0)'

Settings:
Using settings module deltainventory.settings
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {}
ADMINS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
APPEND_SLASH = True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = '********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
BASE_DIR = 'C:\\Ken\\deltainventory'
CACHES = {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = '********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = 31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = []
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': 'C:\\Ken\\deltainventory\\db.sqlite3', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '********************', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = []
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 1000
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%y']
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y', '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y', '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG = True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/html'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER = 'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE = ''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE = ''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = []
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE = None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE = '********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler', 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 0
FIXTURE_DIRS = []
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = None
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'inventory', 'widget_tweaks', 'sweetify']
INTERNAL_IPS = []
LANGUAGES = [('af', 'Afrikaans'), ('ar', 'Arabic'), ('ast', 'Asturian'), ('az', 'Azerbaijani'), ('bg', 'Bulgarian'), ('be', 'Belarusian'), ('bn', 'Bengali'), ('br', 'Breton'), ('bs', 'Bosnian'), ('ca', 'Catalan'), ('cs', 'Czech'), ('cy', 'Welsh'), ('da', 'Danish'), ('de', 'German'), ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'), ('el', 'Greek'), ('en', 'English'), ('en-au', 'Australian English'), ('en-gb', 'British English'), ('eo', 'Esperanto'), ('es', 'Spanish'), ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'), ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'), ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'), ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'), ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'), ('et', 'Estonian'), ('eu', 'Basque'), ('fa', 'Persian'), ('fi', 'Finnish'), ('fr', 'French'), ('fy', 'Frisian'), ('ga', 'Irish'), ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'), ('gl', 'Galician'), ('he', 'Hebrew'), ('hi', 'Hindi'), ('hr', 'Croatian'), ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'), ('hu', 'Hungarian'), ('ia', 'Interlingua'), ('id', 'Indonesian'), ('io', 'Ido'), ('is', 'Icelandic'), ('it', 'Italian'), ('ja', 'Japanese'), ('ka', 'Georgian'), ('kab', 'Kabyle'), ('kk', 'Kazakh'), ('km', 'Khmer'), ('kn', 'Kannada'), ('ko', 'Korean'), ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'), ('lt', 'Lithuanian'), ('lv', 'Latvian'), ('mk', 'Macedonian'), ('ml', 'Malayalam'), ('mn', 'Mongolian'), ('mr', 'Marathi'), ('my', 'Burmese'), ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'), ('ne', 'Nepali'), ('nl', 'Dutch'), ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'), ('os', 'Ossetic'), ('pa', 'Punjabi'), ('pl', 'Polish'), ('pt', 'Portuguese'), ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'), ('ro', 'Romanian'), ('ru', 'Russian'), ('sk', 'Slovak'), ('sl', 'Slovenian'), ('sq', 'Albanian'), ('sr', 'Serbian'), ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'), ('sv', 'Swedish'), ('sw', 'Swahili'), ('ta', 'Tamil'), ('te', 'Telugu'), ('th', 'Thai'), ('tr', 'Turkish'), ('tt', 'Tatar'), ('udm', 'Udmurt'), ('uk', 'Ukrainian'), ('ur', 'Urdu'), ('vi', 'Vietnamese'), ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'), ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI = ['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
LOCALE_PATHS = []
LOGGING = {}
LOGGING_CONFIG = 'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = None
MANAGERS = []
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE = ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES = {}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING = 0
PASSWORD_HASHERS = '********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS = '********************'
PREPEND_WWW = False
ROOT_URLCONF = 'deltainventory.urls'
SECRET_KEY = '********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = False
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = []
SECURE_SSL_HOST = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SERVER_EMAIL = 'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = 'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_FILE_PATH = None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE = 'deltainventory.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND = 'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = []
STATICFILES_DIRS = ['C:\\Ken\\deltainventory\\static']
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder', 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = None
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATES = [{'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', 'DIRS': ['C:\\Ken\\deltainventory\\templates'], 'APP_DIRS': True, 'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug', 'django.template.context_processors.request', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEMPLATE_DIR = 'C:\\Ken\\deltainventory\\templates'
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS = []
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ','
TIME_FORMAT = 'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Manila'
USE_ETAGS = False
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False
USE_TZ = True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT = False
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'deltainventory.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'


You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your
Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will
display a standard page generated by the handler for this status code.
```

Comment: Can you add traceback?

Comment: Sure. how can I do that?

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+I -> Network tab and there you can find all requests and responses from your page

Comment: Edited post. Please see picture. =) Thank you!

Comment: Please press on rhe failed request and open tab response. Copy response and attach to the post.

Comment: Edited again. Thank you! =)

Comment: There is no ptoblem in your post function. The problem is in the `return reverse('part')`. Can you just give `return JsonResponse({"status": "ok"}, status=204)` for returning response from the post function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get internal error because you should return `Response` instance (HttpResponse, HttpRedirectResponse, JsonResponse etc.) not string!

Simple solution return `JsonResponse` and remove  `reverse`.

A little bit harder, but I think better solution, to override `get_template_names` method

```
def get_template_names(self):
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        return ['app/_items_table.html', ]
    return ['app/items_list.html', ]
```

Include `_items_table` into `items_list`. And change `post` response like this:

```
return super(PartListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now on AJAX response you just should replace full table on page and it helps you get rid of page reloading.

Comment: It worked. I imported `from django.http.response import JsonResponse` and the JsonResponse worked. The reason why I commented it out in the first place is because it wasn't working.. so I just tried what I just knew and that is to do the `reverse` thing.

Comment: I will try your better solution. I'll keep in touch. Thank you once again!! =)

Comment: Can you recommend me some sources that can make me learn jquery ajax and django `HttpResponse`, `JsonResponse` better? I'm still a beginner and I'd like to widen my knowledge about it. 

Actually, I want a sweetalert that says `"Successfully deleted"` after the page reloads but it won't show up for some reason. I put it inside the `success` parameter..

Comment: @Kenny I think you can't see alert because you reload page when you get server response. The main idea of second solution - get rid of page reloading, and just update page content on server response

Comment: I see.. it makes sense. Thank you. I'll follow your advice! =)

Comment: I'm trying to follow your advice right now. What should I put in ajax url?

Comment: @Kenny I think `window.location.href` is enough.

Comment: Okay noted. how about in the `success`?

Comment: @Kenny is the success you should replace html of your table. As I wrote in answer you should create separate template for table and include it in page template, after you get response you should replace content of element where you are include this table by response content.

Comment: hi, how exactly should i call the .html of the table? I've never tried doing something like it. Please help =)

Comment: i tried something like this `$('#table-part').html(data);` but it doesn't work correctly. it does delete but it bugs in the middle and I have to refresh to make it work.

Comment: i've also tried `table.ajax.reload();` but it says `"Invalid JSON response"`.

Comment: @Kenny I think `.html` is enough. Are you sure that `data` is correct html? Also I don't know how your table has been built. Has your table been built using django template loop or using some JS library?

Answer (score 1):

Send the csrf token while doing post using ajax post method as below. You can setup the csrf token as shown below in ajax setup method.

Use csrf token while doing post request, this will prevent 500 Server Error

```
// CSRF code
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        var i = 0;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (i; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    // Use csrf token while doing post request, this will prevent 500 Server Error
    $.ajaxSetup({
        crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    }); 


});
```

Answer (score 1):

`reverse` function returns a url in string format which you are returning from the `post` method. It should be a response object. Middleware is trying to get `X-Frame-Options` from response object using `get` but your response is of type `str`.

So return a response object instead of string.